# Rails Pagination Links Not Working With Route for Authenticated Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, pagination, will-paginate, kaminari

I have a problem with pagination with both the `Will_Paginate` and `Kaminari` gems because of this code in the routes:

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'courses#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'home#index', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end 

  root 'home#index'
```

What happens is that when a user is not `signed_in`, then the pagination links display home#index when clicked on (the view shows correctly when a user is logged in).  Even if I comment out the block that has `unauthenticated do...` the same thing happens.

What I noticed is that the links use this naming convention `http://localhost:3000/?page=2`, but if I put `courses` (the model that I'm trying to paginate) in the url, such as `http://localhost:3000/courses?page=2` it displays correctly even if the user is not logged in.

Is there a way that I can continue to direct authenticated users to courses#index by default when they're `signed_in`, but also have pagination links show correctly?

**controller**

```
def index
  @courses = Course.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15).order('created_at DESC')
end
```